# How merge (or rebase) two branches to develop in special situation

Tags: git, merge, repository, git-branch, branching-and-merging

My current state of tree looks like:

```
                Q-W-E (Br2)
               /
----A-B-C-D-E-F-G-H (develop)
       \
        X-Y-Z (Br1)
```

Now, I need merge these two branches to `develop` (in other words `develop` should contains mentioned two new features (branches `Br1` and `Br2`)).

The problem is that before merging `Br2` I should merge `Br1`.  The cause is:  `Br1` contains some code which is needed in feature on branch `Br2` (feature on `Br2` is almost finished - I need add one small commmit which will use some code available on `Br1`, exactly one function must be called - this function is implemented on branch `Br1`).

Additionally, both branches are not fresh in comparison to `develop`.

I ask for help step by step (even exact command) because I am newbie at git and I know that it is easy to make a mistake. Obviously, I have some experience, I know merge, rebase, commit and much more, however this experience is too poor to make an experiment on repository.

Comment: Probably just a typo or equivalent, but: you have two `E` commits. Maybe br2 should point to `R` of `Q-W-R`?

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with the tree:

```
                Q-W-R (Br2)
               /
----A-B-C-D-E-F-G-H (develop)
       \
        X-Y-Z (Br1)
```

(I renamed second E to R).

The simple and strightforward way to merge is:

1. Backup you repository (you do regular backups anyway, right?)
2. `git checkout develop`
3. `git merge Br1`

3a. If there are merge conflicts — resolve, add and commit to finish merge.

```
                    Q-W-R (Br2)
                   /
    ----A-B-C-D-E-F-G-H-M1 (develop)
           \           /       ^
            X-Y-Z (Br1)       HEAD
```

4. `git merge Br2`

4a. If there are merge conflicts — resolve, add and commit to finish merge.

```
                Q-W-R (Br2)
               /      \
----A-B-C-D-E-F-G-H-M1-M2 (develop)
       \           /          ^
        X-Y-Z (Br1)          HEAD
```